# setting a datetime variable

Tags: sql, datetime, printing

In SQL I do the following code.  When the print section runs it returns 'Dec 31 2050 11:59PM'.  I use the variable in later parts of the code (not shown) and it doesn't work and i get a "Conversion failed when converting character string to smalldatetime data type" error.

Have I confused my formats?  I thought datetime came through as 'yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss' but clearly i must be wrong.  Every place i look at the datetim format says this should work, so I don't know what I'm doing wrong.

```
        declare @date int

--@date is yyyymm format


declare @sql_v_fx as varchar(max), @sql_dim_for_exc as varchar(max)
declare @maxEndDate as smalldatetime

set @date = 201202
set @maxEndDate = Convert(smalldatetime, '2050-12-31 23:59', 101)

print @maxenddate

--remove prior date in [zstbl_fx_rollback]
truncate table zstbl_fx_rollback 

--insert the user entered month
--specify in the VS report whether it's Balance Sheet or Income Statement date
insert into [zstbl_fx_rollback] (yyyymm) select @date

--alter the v_fx view to into account the date in the [zstbl_fx_rollback] table
select @sql_v_fx = 
'
    Alter view [dbo].[v_fx] as
    select 
          [foreign exchange key],[currency key], [to usd], [from usd], [effective date], 
          [expiration date] = 
                case when [effective date] = 
                      convert(datetime,cast((select isnull(max(yyyymm),205012) from zstbl_fx_rollback) * 100 + 1 as char(8))) then ' + @maxEndDate + ' else [expiration date] end
          ,[is current] 
          ,[effective date key] = year([effective date]) * 10000 + month([effective date])*100

    from crs..[dim foreign exchange]
    where [effective date] <= convert(datetime,cast((select isnull(max(yyyymm),205012) from zstbl_fx_rollback) * 100 + 1 as char(8))) 
'

exec(@sql_v_fx)
```

Comment: what is the code that is generating the conversion error? I don't see anything wrong with this code - does what it's supposed to do.

Comment: yes this should work, can you post code where this error is thrown? I executed this and i don't get any error - `SELECT 1 WHERE @maxEndDate > GETDATE()`, `SELECT 1 WHERE CAST(@maxEndDate as smalldatetime) > GETDATE()`

Comment: you cannot do this - `SELECT 1 WHERE '2050-12-31 23:59:00' * 10000 > GETDATE()` multiply varchar date string with 10000

Comment: @seanW My apologies all, I updated the original post. Just as an FYI, the reason I'm setting the code as a string is I'm updating a view with a stored procedure and it's the only way I could get that to work. And because the string has issues with tick marks and plus signs what should be very easy has become a circuitous nightmare. –

Comment: this part of code -  `then ' + @maxEndDate + '` replace with then `''' + @maxEndDate + '''`

Comment: Good lord, ar eyou kidding me?  There it is, extra tick marks.  I actually went back and found I could just put the actual value into the code and do away with the whole variable (it was unnecessary as that value isn't changing ever)  Thanks for fixing my problem...and making me hate single quote marks.

Answer (score 0):

if this is `Sql-Server`
try

```
set @maxEndDate = Convert(smalldatetime, '2050-12-31 23:59', 101)
```

if you need another format of date, check this link
http://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/ms187928.aspx

Comment: When I do print @maxEndDate I still get ''Dec 31 2050 11:59PM'

Comment: show us the places where you use maxEndDate and give you an error. The problem is not format, because it's just the way that sql show you the date. There is some problem with the data types, are you missing a cast or something ? Show us the query when you got the error

Comment: My apologies all, I updated the original post.  Just as an FYI, the reason I'm setting the code as a string is I'm updating a view with a stored procedure and it's the only way I could get that to work.  And because the string has issues with tick marks and plus signs what should be very easy has become a circuitous nightmare.